# Output of a Python program doesn't make sense

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I have written one program in python which displays the maximum of three numbers.. Although the program is easy the output is raising a question.. Here is the code that I have written ::

```
 #Program to find maximum of three numbers using function
def max_of_three(a,b,c):
    if(a>b and a>c):
        print("a is greater")
    elif(b>a and b>c):
        print("b is greater")
    else:
        print("c is greater")
print("Enter three numbers...")
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
print(max_of_three(a,b,c))
```

Now when I am running this program and getting this output after providing inputs at runtime::

```
Enter three numbers...
58
45
12
a is greater
None
```

The reesult is fine.. But what I don't understand is that why the word "None" is getting printed? I mean what does it mean?

Comment: remove the last print, ie `max_of_three(a,b,c)` would be enough since you added `print` func inside that function.

Comment: Python also allows you to lose the `and` in your conditions i.e.

    if a > b > c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(max_of_three(a,b,c))` Is trying to print the result of `max_of_three` - but there isn't one - hence `None`.

Looks like you intended `max_of_three` to return a string instead of printing the value directly. This is "better" since it splits the display of the "state" from the calculation.

Alternative would be to just call `max_of_three` (without `print`) i.e. `max_of_three(a,b,c);` This works, but now your calculation always prints the results (even if you don't want it to print)

Comment: i.e. Python functions implicitly return `None`. See https://books.google.com.au/books?id=M2D5nnYlmZoC&pg=PT182&lpg=PT182&dq=python+implicitly+returns+none&source=bl&ots=vXXFEr7PLR&sig=yHmltvvVJL-SQxeHcBYyX4PijA4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5po3Mv5nKAhWjMKYKHcsDBCgQ6AEIUjAI#v=onepage&q=python%20implicitly%20returns%20none&f=false

Comment: Thank you..this clears my doubt.. I actually didn't think about it... The function is actually printing and I put the function in a print statement.. I shouldn't have done that... Thank you for your reply.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't return any values in your function `max_of_three(a,b,c)`, the function returns nothing, so the output is `None`.

Assuming by your comment `#Program to find maximum of three numbers using function`,  you may have meant by returning the biggest value:

```
def max_of_three(a,b,c):
    if(a>b and a>c):
        print("a is greater")
        return a
    elif(b>a and b>c):
        print("b is greater")
        return b
    else:
        print("c is greater")
        return c
```

Now, the function should return the greatest value, which is 58:

```
Enter three numbers...
58
45
12
a is greater
58
```

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying ... It has been a big help.. :)